How do I force monochrome (white text on black background)?
I am an old man with bad eyes and am colorblind. I have programmed in many languages over 50+ years and am just getting around to playing with Python on Windows 11.
Many of the colors used in the Python shell make the text unreadable to me. I have been looking for a way to kill all coloring in the shell so I can at least read the screen, but have not found a way to do it. I've tried os.system("color 70") but the colors come right back, apparently because the command is executed in a subshell.
Any help would be appreciated (otherwise I'll have to give up on Python) :-(.
I've tried os.system("color 70") but the colors come right back in the >>> prompt that is almost invisible to me, apparently because the command is executed in a subshell.

Do you need to use code for this or would just changing the terminal settings work?

When you say "Python shell", do you mean Idle or some other IDE? If you run python from an ordinary terminal, it doesn't try to change the underlying terminal colors at all.

Any chances you run color 70 or color 07 before you run a python interpreter? It works on my Windows Terminal.

You already got some reasonable pieces of advice in comments related to pure console (command-line) work. But I can add at least one option for the IDE.
You could use Visual Studio Code (VSCode), free, open-source, and multi-platform. It is the best environment for working with many different software technologies, they come in the form of VSCode extensions. Python is certainly one of them. But what I suggest also applies to some other development environments.
You don't really need a colorless design, you just need the color scheme to be contrast enough for your vision. I understand that you need tonal contrast and not color contrast. With VSCode, you can use main menu > File > Preferences > Theme… and select the theme of your liking. Some of them provide extremely good contrast. If you don't like them, you can check out the themes on Visual Studio Marketplace to find some more suitable Theme extension.

FYI comments are not for arguing about how this site is moderated, or for extended discussion. Aside from that: the question itself is off-topic. And posting an answer suggesting a product or service is a recommendation (and recommendation questions are expressly off-topic). This has nothing to do with someone wanting to be helpful - it's about the site's guidelines.

@David Makogon — I know and agree. This is not my initiative.
